# Active list element depending on day of week

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a website utilizing HTML, JavaScript and CSS(Big woop - I know).

I'm running bootstrap to learn how to make a website a bit more responsive. I'm currently trying to learn the different date functions in JavaScript and want my website to highlight different list-elements depending on what day of the week it is.

```
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" >Mondays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Tuesdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Wednesdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Thursdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Fridays: 09:00 - 12:00</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Saturdays: Closed</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Sundays: Closed</li>
                </ul>
```

The list itself is a standard unordered list which displays opening hours and what I want to create through JavaScript is that if the website senses that today is Monday it'll highlight Monday.

I have written the following code to get the website to check date:

```
function daysOpen(){

let daysOfWeek = ['Sunday','Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
let dateObject = new Date()
let today = dateObject.getDay();
//console.log("Today is: " + today); // generates output to console
//console.log(daysOfWeek[today]) <- This is used for debugging

if(daysOfWeek[today] === 'Saturday' || daysOfWeek[today] ==='Sunday'){ // This piece of code lets me check date from
    //system time(?) and compare against my array to see if today is open or closed
    console.log("Store is closed")
}
else
{
    console.log("The store is open")
}
```

}

This is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to use the if-statements to highlight the list elements and I haven't been able to find a good example or guide online. The most similar question I could find was this: [text depend on time of day and day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831660/text-depend-on-time-of-day-and-day-of-week)

But I'm still having troubles understanding how to continue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter html like as follows.

```js
function daysOpen() {
  let daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  let dateObject = new Date()
  let today = dateObject.getDay();

  if (daysOfWeek[today] === 'Saturday' || daysOfWeek[today] === 'Sunday') {
    let elem = document.querySelector("li.day-" + today);
    elem.classList.add("highlight");
    console.log("Store is closed")
  } else {
    console.log("The store is open")
  }
}

daysOpen();
```

```css
li.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item day-1">Mondays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item day-2">Tuesdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item day-3">Wednesdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item day-4">Thursdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item day-5">Fridays: 09:00 - 12:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item day-7">Saturdays: Closed</li>
  <li class="list-group-item day-0">Sundays: Closed</li>
</ul>
```

Changes added are

> 1. Added custom css for highlighted class
> 2. Added unique class name based on day code for each class
> 3. Added class highlight based on our If condition

Don't forget to initialize the function call when needed

> ***Suggestion*** : If possible pass the date from back-end code would be
>   more trusty. Plugin like jQuery helps us to reduce our efforts to
>   write these kind of codes and reduces line of codes too.

Comment: Thank you Mohammed! This actually made it a lot easier to keep going. I was struggling to understand how get it all to work together. I'll use your answer and try to read a bit more documentation. Especially in regard of your suggestion with the back-end code. 

Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way with a ternary operator.
If you just need to retrieve the day you can chain Day() method like this.

Edit: I added a method if you want to set a style for the active day and another for all the inactive days

```js
/*first method only highlight active day*/
let today = new Date().getDay();
let okDay = document.getElementById(today);

today !== 0 && today !== 6 ?
  okDay.classList.add("open-day") :
  okDay.classList.add("close-day");

/*********************
 *edit second method *
 *********************/
const weekDays = document.querySelectorAll("li[data-day]");

function getCurrentDay() {
  Array.prototype.map.call(weekDays, d => {
    +d.dataset.day === today && (today !== 0 || today !== 6) ?
      d.classList.add("open-day") :
      d.classList.add("close-day");
  });
}
getCurrentDay();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list-group-item {
  list-style: none;
  color: gray;
}

.open-day {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.close-day {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" id="1">Mondays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="2">Tuesdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="3">Wednesdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="4">Thursdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="5">Fridays: 09:00 - 12:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="6">Saturdays: Closed</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="0">Sundays: Closed</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-day="1">Mondays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-day="2">Tuesdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-day="3">Wednesdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-day="4">Thursdays: 09:00 - 16:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-day="5">Fridays: 09:00 - 12:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-day="6">Saturdays: Closed</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-day="0">Sundays: Closed</li>
</ul>
```